# Extra Grant Pop up when requesting for Google Calendar permission

Tags: reactjs, google-calendar-api, google-apps, google-signin

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Google shows the above 3 popups to users when they try to signup using google on my website, but it doesn't show the same popup to me when I try to signup.** What I see is just this -

[image]

These 3 separate pop-ups are causing huge drop-offs from my website. How can I remove these 3 different permission pop-ups?

Google Login button details - Using [React Google Login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login)

```
    <div className="manager-signup-container">
      <div className="content">Join Peoplebox as a Manager to have productive 1:1s that drive actions.</div>
      <GoogleLogin
      className={`google-btn-${this.state.loginbtnStatus}`}
      clientId={GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
      buttonText="Sign up with Google"
      onSuccess={(response) => this.responseOauth(response, "google")}
      onFailure={this.responseGoogleFail}
      responseType="code"
      scope="profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"
      accessType="offline"
      prompt="consent"
      disabled={this.state.loginDisabled}
    />
```

Comment: I am handling this by checking for the scope returned when I exchange the `code` for `auth_token`. But if anyone finds a way to skip this pop, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The Authorisation process for Third-party Google apps has recently changed to allow the user to accept only the permissions he/she desires. This way, the user has more control on the access the applications have on his/her data.

At the moment, **there is no way to change this behaviour** nor there is any public documentation/resources on this change.

Comment: But older apps don't ask for these permissions while I sign up on them for example - [calendly](https://calendly.com/signup)